# Error Saving Membership Transactions After Upgrading To 5.13.4

Tags: civimember, contributions

I am getting the following error on screen when trying to save a membership with a contribution after upgrading to 5.13.4.

We had this problem with all contributions at first but that appears to have resolved itself.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

When looking in the logs I see the full backtrace before that this is listed as the `[to_string]`.

`nativecode=1442 **Can't update table 'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Here is the backtrace:

```
#1 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...")
#3 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...")
#4 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...", "1442 ** Can't update table'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger becau...")
#7 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...")
#9 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...")
#10 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1040): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...")
#11 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(572): DB_DataObject->insert()
#12 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(231): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
#13 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(957): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::add((Array:30))
#14 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1771): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm::processFormContribution(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), (Array:66),(Array:62), (Array:30), Object(CRM_Financial_DAO_FinancialType), TRUE, 5, NULL)
#15 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1487): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processSecondaryFinancialTransaction("69090",Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), (Array:62), FALSE, (Array:1), "1.000000000", "2")
#16 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(1392): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcessMembership((Array:60), "69090",Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), (Array:52), (Array:0), (Array:0), (Array:13), (Array:1), FALSE, NULL, TRUE, "2", (Array:1), FALSE)
#17 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2415): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processMembership((Array:60), "69090", (Array:0), (Array:0), (Array:52), (Array:1))
#18 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(2290): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->doMembershipProcessing("69090", (Array:60), (Array:52), (Array:1))
#19 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Confirm.php(709): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->processFormSubmission("69090")
#20 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(490): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm->postProcess()
#21 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#22 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next", "Next")
#23 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")
#24 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm), "next")
#25 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(349): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#26 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#27 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#28 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#29 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#30 /home/customer/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("contribute", "transact")
#31 /home/customer/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#32 {main}
```

There was a similar issue that was resolved for version 4.4.2 - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-13587.

I tested the site without our custom extensions enabled and they do not impact the problem. The following extensions are enabled.

- Birthday Report
- CiviDiscount
- Extended Report
- Summary Fields
- Report Error

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: are you able to replicate this on eg demo.dmaster.civicrm.org as this would help confirm if this is a global issue or one particular to your set up. also do you have any extensions etc which may be affecting this feature?

Comment: I could not reproduce this in dmaster. I did add list of the extensions we have enabled in the post. I tired to do the same transactions and they cannot be made with or without our custom extensions enabled. Thank you!

Comment: so even with all Extensions disabled, c_templates cleared etc etc you still cannot save a Contribution?

Comment: I just checked one more time with deleting  templates_c and we can save contributions but not memberships that have contributions.

Comment: sounding weirder. are you certain you aren't flipping between www and no www etc

Comment: "#6 /home/customer/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_contribution (contact_id , financial_type_id , contributi...", "1442 ** Can't update table'civicrm_contact' in stored function/trigger becau...")"

So this looks like it relates to logging - do you have that enabled. Try disabling & re-neabling it - esp if you are on a multilingual site. There is also an api to do a schema update on a multilingual site - it could be that

Comment: I am having the same problem after turning on and off logging (logging was not turned on but a log table was defined in civicrm.settings.php).Now it is off and the table is not referenced in civicrm.settings.php. I ran the multilingual schema update too but no such luck. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

After reading many posts and looking through the ideas I got here I deleted the triggers for the contributions table and rebuilt the triggers (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#trigger-rebuild) for the table. This appears to have worked like a charm.

-Steve